# How to create JOB in AS400?

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm new to AS400 DB2 , I have 3 procedures in AS400, now those procedure should be execute by calling single job in AS400.

Can you tell me please how to create a job and execute job in AS400 DB2 Mainframe ?

Comment: In addition to Charles' answer, you might want to read the Work Management document in IBM's Knowledge Center https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaks/rzaks1.htm

Answer (score 3):

1. You're probably not using an AS/400 running OS/400; they have been obsolete for 10 years.  You're probably using a POWER server running IBM i.
2. POWER servers are not mainframes, they are mid-range systems.

On the IBM i, a job is [how the operating system organizes, tracks, and processes work.](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzal2/rzal2jobs.htm)  On other platforms, you'd call it a process.

Jobs are the basis of [work management](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaks/rzakswmintro.htm)

When you sign onto a 5250 session, the system starts an "interactive job" to service your requests.  You can't call procedures directly, but you can call a program that then calls the procedures.

There are plenty of [common jobs tasks](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaks/rzaksmngjbcmntsk.htm).  Including the use of [Submit Job (SBMJOB) command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzaks/rzakssmtjobonce.htm) to submit a job to run in batch.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to run 3 programs in by invoking a single command. Is that it?

In OS/400 (haven't used it in over a decade) you put the commands for the programs into a CL source and compile it. Unlike .bat files on Windows, CL isn't going to run without compilation.

Refer to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/rbam6/creat.htm for how to create a CL program.